# Magento add comment at checkout

Tags: magento

Im trying to allow my customers to add a comment to their orders. So i searched after an extension and i found one. The setup seems pretty easy ...
you just got to make sure that a block is being loaded at the checkout.xml

```
<block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
```

Link to Magemaven OrderComment:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magemaven-ordercomment.html

But the textfield isnt showing up. My guess is that another extension (MageSetup) is causing this. When i activate the template hints it shows me a different layout instead of what is set at the checkout.xml. There are some phtml loaded from "magesetup" folder.

I have Magento DE 1.9 installed. Can someone explain me why the checkout.xml isnt loaded? Is there some sort trick to load stuff via database i dont know of?

Edit:
i tried to follow this tutorial, but it seems that something went wrong http://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-add-order-comment-on-customer-checkout-in-magento/

how can i check if this script was executed correctly?

```
$c = array (
‘entity_type_id’  => 1234,
‘attribute_code’  => ‘myorder_customercomment’,
‘backend_type’    => ‘text’,     // MySQL-DataType
‘frontend_input’  => ‘textarea’, // Type of the HTML-Form-Field
‘is_global’       => ‘1’,
‘is_visible’      => ‘1’,
‘is_required’     => ‘0’,
‘is_user_defined’ => ‘0’,
‘frontend_label’  => ‘Customer Comment’,
);
$attribute = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute();
$attribute->loadByCode($c[‘entity_type_id’], $c[‘attribute_code’])
->setStoreId(0)
->addData($c);
$attribute->save();
```

I think that something is missing because the class is missing the method getMyorderCustomercomment. Or is this Method being generated automatically?

```
MyCompany_MyOrder_Helper_CustomerOrderComment extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
     public function setCustomerOrderComment($observer) {
          $orderComment = $this->_getRequest()->getPost(‘myCustomerOrderComment’, false);
          $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->setMyorderCustomercomment($orderComment);
     }
}
```

**Update:**
the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <MyCompany_MyOrder>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </MyCompany_MyOrder>
        </modules>
        <helpers>
            <myorder>
                <class>MyCompany_MyOrder_Helper</class>
            </myorder>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
                <observers>
                    <myorder_set_customerordercomment>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>MyCompany_MyOrder_Helper_CustomerOrderComment</class>
                        <method>setCustomerOrderComment</method>
                    </myorder_set_customerordercomment>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

the helper:

```
<?php
class MyCompany_MyOrder_Helper_CustomerOrderComment extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function setCustomerOrderComment($observer) {
        $orderComment = $this->_getRequest()->getPost('myCustomerOrderComment', false);

        mail('my@email.com', 'TestMail', $orderComment);

        $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->setMyorderCustomercomment($orderComment)->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create one order attribute and place field in phtml file. There is a detailed blog here which you can try: http://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-add-order-comment-on-customer-checkout-in-magento/

**Update**
open database and open eav_attribute table - search for myorder_customercomment in attribute_code field. If there is a record, the script executed successfully.

setMyorderCustomercomment only sets the comment entered by user in the attribute that you created. Magento provides magic methods(get and set) so you dont need to re-define getMyorderCustomercomment() method.

When you do echo $_order->getMyorderCustomercomment(); if your attribute is created successfully, magento will automatically fetch its value from database and echo it.

The reason why the article specified the set method is so that you can access the method from various files without having to repeat the code. You can avoid specifying that function and simply write $order->setMyorderCustomercomment($orderComment)->save(); and it will work.

Read more about the magento magic methods here: http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2012/04/06/magic-methods-inside-magento/

**Answer to your query:**
how are you calling that function ? it is supposed to be called like this: Mage::helper('modulename')->setCustomerOrderComment($arguments);
Make sure you replace modulename in above statement with your actual module name.

If your function is in observer file then it will be called automatically after checkout_type_onepage_save_order event is fired. so check where u have written your function helper file or observer file and provide proper details which of these function is not being called. If observer function is not being called you will have to check which event is being fired when you place the order. Due to Character limit in comments i am unable to post this in comment section so updated my answer instead.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The attribute_code "myorder_customercomment" exists in eav_attribute. Is there a way to check in the database if the field was set? Because i think the actual problem is that, i dont know if i cant load the attribute or if the attribute wasnt set. I even tried send an email in this function but i didnt receive the email.

i tried to echo the value, but i didnt get anything, so my guess is that the function isnt being loaded to save the attribute: $_order = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->load(100000608); echo $_order->getMyorderCustomercomment();

Is there a way to check if the function is run?

Comment: Load is used to load order by entity id. You are loading it by increment id so try following: $_order = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->loadByIncrementId(100000608); $_order->getMyorderCustomercomment(); See if a column myorder_customercomment is created or not in sales_flat_order. If there is not a column then create 1 with type text. then Clear all caches, save the customer comment in an order and then check value corresponding to your order in sales_flat_order table's myorder_customercomment column. Check this link to see how to create an order attribute properly: http://goo.gl/R21YNp

Comment: Loading the Model and getting the value by getMyorderCustomercomment() works perfectly. But it still isnt set automatically. Back to my question again: the function setCustomerOrderComment at the class MyCompany_MyOrder_Helper_CustomerOrderComment  isnt being loaded. i tried to send an email to me from this function, but it didnt work. how to test it?

Comment: The function is not called at all. i thought the config file would do that automatically when someone completes an order? i updated my question so you see the 2 files.

Comment: when you write it in config.xml the corresponding function is supposed to be in MyCompany/MyOrder/Model/Observer.php file. Magento is not able to find anything in observer file so nothing happens. You are writing your code in helper file. When you write anything in helper file you have to explicitly call that function. Write your code in observer.php and it should work fine

Comment: So i put the Helper to the location "/httpdocs/app/code/local/MyCompany/MyOrder/Model/Observer.php" and my config is at "/httpdocs/app/code/local/MyCompany/MyOrder/etc/config.xml". The function is NOT being called. :(